# Is it better to upload in parts or multipart compression and upload

Tags: java, compression, file-transfer

My application is used to upload rather big files (~500mb) and some of them are failing.

To raise the successrate I want to implement uploading in parts.

My question is:

**What is better preformance-/safetywise, uploading a compressed file bit by bit (using APPE) or compressing the file in multiple parts, then uploading it part by part?**

Note that the file is going to be uncompressed on "the other side"

If any road is better, is there any library that can keep me from reinventing the wheel? :)

Comment: do you have control over the client side? is it just a browser?

Comment: I got control, using a Web start app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a class that zips the file into separate parts and then uploads the parts separately.

I still don't know what is better from performance/safety perspective, but my guess is that the difference is minimal.

I felt safer having separate files with well defined boundaries between files instead of trying to keep track on how many bytes had been transferred.

If anyone want the zipping class, give me a shout.